# Undefined offset errorin 1 in php

Tags: php, arrays, pdf, fpdf

I couldn't find the error in indexing.Can you please help me to fix this up.
Error is in the second loop of the fancyTable function.

> Error is something like this Undefined offset in 0, Undefined offset
>   in 1, Undefined offset in 2, Undefined offset in 3

```
class PDF extends FPDF {


function LoadData() {
    //Read file lines
    $con = new Connection();
    $connect = $con->getConnection();

    $sector = $_POST['text_sector'];
    $start_yr = $_POST['text_start_year'];
    $end_yr = $_POST['text_end_year'];

    if ($start_yr != '' || $end_yr != '') {
        if ($end_yr == '') {
            $end_yr = date("Y-m-d");
        }
        if ($start_yr == '') {
            $start_yr = strtotime('' . date("Y-m-d") . ' -10 year');
            $start_yr = date("Y-m-d", $start_yr);
        }

        //echo $start_yr;
        //echo $end_yr;
        $sql = "sql is too long to write here";                
    } else {

        $sql = 'sql is too long to write here';
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
    $dataArray = array(); // make a new array to hold all your data
    $index = 0;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
        $dataArray[$index] = $row;
        $index++;
    }
    return $dataArray;
}


function FancyTable($header, $data) {
    $this->SetFillColor(255, 0, 0);
    $this->SetTextColor(255);
    $this->SetDrawColor(128, 0, 0);
    $this->SetLineWidth(.3);
    $this->SetFont('', 'B');
    //Header

    $w = array(25, 50, 25, 25, 35);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($header); $i++) {
        $this->Cell($w[$i], 7, $header[$i], 1, 0, 'C', 1);
    }
    $this->Ln();

    //Color and font restoration
    $this->SetFillColor(224, 235, 255);
    $this->SetTextColor(0);
    $this->SetFont('');
    //Data
    $fill = 0;

    foreach ($data as $row) {
        //$pdf->Cell($w, $h, $txt, $border, $ln, $align)
        $this->Cell($w[0], 6, $row[0], 'LR', 0, 'L', $fill);
        $this->Cell($w[1], 6, $row[1], 'LR', 0, 'L', $fill);
        $this->Cell($w[2], 6, $row[2], 'LR', 0, 'L', $fill);
        $this->Cell($w[3], 6, $row[3], 'LR', 0, 'L', $fill);
        $this->Cell($w[4], 6, number_format($row[4]), 'LR', 0, 'R', $fill);
        $this->Ln();
        $fill = !$fill;
    }

    $this->Cell(array_sum($w), 0, '', 'T');
}

}

$pdf = new PDF();
//Column titles
$header = array(' No', 'Name', 'Client', 'Completed Date', 'Total Amount');

$dataArray = $pdf->LoadData();

$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 12);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->FancyTable($header, $dataArray);

$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Comment: you're trying to access an array index that doesn't exist. You'll have to `var_dump($w, $row)` to see what you're really dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_fetch_assoc` returns an associative array, indexed by column name.
For a numerically indexed result use `mysqli_fetch_row`:

```
function LoadData() {
    //your sql generating code here
    $dataArray = array(); // make a new array to hold all your data
    //$index = 0;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) { 
        $dataArray[] = $row;
        //$index++;
    }
    return $dataArray;
}
```

Also the `$index` variable is not required, simply using `$array[] = $var` syntax will add a new element to an array with an ascending numerical index

Comment: Thank you so much. That was very helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

[mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) returns field names as key

```
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
    $dataArray[$index] = $row;
    $index++;
 }
```

becomes

```
 $dataArray[0]["fieldname"] = "value";
```

And you are trying to grab the field by integer key

```
 foreach ($data as $row) {
    //$pdf->Cell($w, $h, $txt, $border, $ln, $align)
    $this->Cell($w[0], 6, $row[0], 'LR', 0, 'L', $fill);
    $this->Cell($w[1], 6, $row[1], 'LR', 0, 'L', $fill);
    $this->Cell($w[2], 6, $row[2], 'LR', 0, 'L', $fill);
    $this->Cell($w[3], 6, $row[3], 'LR', 0, 'L', $fill);
    $this->Cell($w[4], 6, number_format($row[4]), 'LR', 0, 'R', $fill);
    $this->Ln();
    $fill = !$fill;
}
```

Either you can replace $row[0]..$row[3] with field names like $row['fieldname'] or  you can use [mysql_fetch_row](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php) instead of mysql_fetch_assoc